# JVM / Shell program execution / RAM Utilization

Tags: jvm, ram

I'm calling a bunch of shell programs from a program running on the JVM. When I execute a program like imagemagick, does it use my system's RAM or does it use RAM allocated to the JVM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run (shell) executables, they will use their own memory space in system RAM.

If you instead load DLLs using for example JNI and execute that code, they will be loaded into Java's memory space.